# Using consts in static classes

Tags: c#, static, constants

I was plugging away on [an open source project](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/) this past weekend when I ran into [a bit of code that confused me](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/source/browse/src/NodaTime/Format/FormatUtils.cs) to look up the usage in the [C# specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336809.aspx).

The code in questions is as follows:

```
internal static class SomeStaticClass
{
    private const int CommonlyUsedValue = 42;

    internal static string UseCommonlyUsedValue(...)
    {
        // some code
        value = CommonlyUsedValue + ...;

        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

I was caught off guard because this appears to be a non static field being used by a static function which some how compiled just fine in a static class!

The specification states (§10.4):

> A constant-declaration may include a
>   set of attributes (§17), a new
>   modifier (§10.3.4), and a valid
>   combination of the four access
>   modifiers (§10.3.5). The attributes
>   and modifiers apply to all of the
>   members declared by the
>   constant-declaration. **Even though
>   constants are considered static
>   members, a constant-declaration
>   neither requires nor allows a static
>   modifier.** It is an error for the same
>   modifier to appear multiple times in a
>   constant declaration.

So now it makes a little more sense because *constants are considered static members*, but the rest of the sentence is a bit surprising to me.  Why is it that *a constant-declaration neither requires nor allows a static modifier*?  Admittedly I did not know the spec well enough for this to immediately make sense in the first place, but **why was the decision made to not force constants to use the static modifier if they are considered static?**

Looking at the last sentence in that paragraph, I cannot figure out if it is regarding the previous statement directly and there is some implicit static modifier on constants to begin with, or if it stands on its own as another rule for constants.  Can anyone help me clear this up?

Comment: Maybe they chose not to allow **static** because it could lead to confusion: someone seeing "static const foo..." may mistakenly believe that **static** actually makes a *difference*, implying that you could remove it and somehow have a non-static const.

Comment: You get a very decent compiler error message when you try to use `static` and `const` together. I think that is good enough.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Basically, **const** implies **static** already, since the value cannot be changed at runtime.    There's no reason for you to ever declare *static const*, since it's already implied, and the language designers decided to make the language syntax reflect that.

The specification language is basically saying "Const is always static, so you can't explicitly say static and const since it's redundant."

Comment: If that is the case, then why do they allow you explicitly use private on just about everything in the language?

Comment: Adding private doesn't suggest a different meaning.  Here, if the allowed "const variable" and "static const variable", it would suggest that there were non-static const options.  Private doesn't define the **storage** of a variable, but is more of a decorator describing it's **accessability** - adding or removing it doesn't really change meaning, but adds a descriptive element to the type.

Comment: By allowing private to be added or left off suggests that there are non-private member options, which there are. :)

Comment: I think I am starting to see the point, though it is a bit contradictory to my normal usage of explicitly specifying just about everything.  I would have probably advocated some kind of compiler warning or something when attempting to not specify a constant as static.

Comment: +1. Private is simply the *default* accessibility modifier for a class member. `static` is not the default for constants, it's the only option.

Comment: @Nick: Would you advocate decorating all function parameters as being passed by value (like VB.NET does for auto-generated signatures)?

Comment: @Nick leaving of the access modifier means different things in differrent contexts. The default is not always private. It might be internal. The const is never associated with an instance. How would that work? I'd say it would be _very_ confusing if you could do static const which would imply that you could have an instance constant as well but then I guess if you have a c++ background you might read const as readonly (aka writable once) and then suddenly instanceness makes sense. In C# however const is constant and readonly is well almost readonly :p

Answer (score 61):

UPDATE: [This question was the subject of my blog on June 10th, 2010.](https://ericlippert.com/2010/06/10/dont-repeat-yourself-consts-are-already-static/) Thanks for the great question!

> why was the decision made to not force constants to use the static modifier if they are considered static?

Suppose constants are considered to be static. There are three possible choices:

1. Make static **optional**: "const int x..." or "static const int x..." are both legal.
2. Make static **required**: "const int x..." is illegal, "static const int x..." is legal
3. Make static **illegal**: "const int x..." is legal, "static const int x..." is illegal.

Your question is why did we choose (3)?

The design notes from 1999 do not say; I just checked. But we can deduce what was probably going through the language designer's heads.

The problem with (1) is that you could read code that uses both "const int x..." and "static const int y..." and then you would naturally ask yourself "what's the difference?"  Since the default for non-constant fields and methods is "instance" unless "static", the natural conclusion would be that some constants are per-instance and some are per-type, and that conclusion would be wrong. This is bad because it is misleading.

The problem with (2) is that first off, it is redundant. It's just more typing without adding clarity or expressiveness to the language. And second, I don't know about you, but I personally hate it when the compiler gives me the error "You forgot to say the magic word right here. I know you forgot to say the magic word, I am one hundred percent capable of figuring out that the magic word needs to go there, but I'm not going to let you get any work done until you say the magic word".

The problem with (3) is that the developer is required to know that const logically implies static.  However, once the developer learns this fact, they've learned it. It's not like this is a complex idea that is hard to figure out.

The solution which presents the fewest problems and costs to the end user is (3).

It is interesting to compare and contrast this with other places in the language where different decisions were made.

For example, overloaded operators are required to be both public and static. In this case, again we are faced with three options:

1. make public static optional,
2. make it required, or
3. make it illegal.

For overloaded operators we chose (2). Since the natural state of a method is private/instance it seems bizarre and misleading to make something that looks like a method public/static invisibly, as (1) and (3) both require.

For another example, a virtual method with the same signature as a virtual method in a base class is supposed to have either "new" or "override" on it. Again, three choices.

1. make it optional: you can say new, or override, or nothing at all, in which case we default to new.
2. make it required: you have to say new or override, or
3. make it illegal: you cannot say new at all, so if you don't say override then it is automatically new.

In this case we chose (1) because that works best for the brittle base class situation of someone adds a virtual method to a base class that you don't realize you are now overriding. This produces a warning, but not an error.

My point is that each of these situations has to be considered on a case-by-case basis. There's not much general guidance here.

Comment: I like your point about static being a "magic word" in this case.  Still I don't think that is enough to tip the scales for me, however, option 1 would still be more confusing, and after all the comments in this thread, I can understand the reasoning for 3.  The converse of this situation, where the compiler does throw an error if I had tried to make a constant static, would have left me with similar questions.

Comment: +1 for authority and use the of "magic word". Not necessarily in that order! ;)

Comment: Coming from the blog: maybe it's just me, but i find that not needing static just confuses me. If i don't see the word static, then i assume that it's an instance variable. It doesn't help that you can access it either way from inside the class (this.MyConstant or MyClassName.MyConstant). Further, i thought the point of statically typed languages was to make more typing without adding expressivity or clarity ;) @Adam Robinson: Surely you meant *use of the* not *use the of* ;)

Comment: @RCIX: Enjoy Yodaspeak often I do.

Comment: Hi Eric, your blogs are linked to quite often on Stack Exchange - what do you want my script to do with the links which are no longer working? Yours is the only one (AFAIK) on MSDN with that login page; no idea why. I can easily have the script ignore that, and automatically replace it with a Wayback Machine copy instead, like you did.

Comment: @Glorfindel: Thanks for asking! I'm glad to hear this problem is being solved. I find it extraordinarily vexing that Microsoft has changed the links to my blogs some four times now; I can't even keep up. My opinion is: link to the internet archive version.

Comment: @Glorfindel: Longer term, I am gradually moving all the content on my MSDN blog to ericlippert.com but it is a slow process and I have many other pressing concerns taking up my free time right now. I'll update links here to point to the ericlippert.com copy at a later date.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I hadn't found your new website yet. I've adapted the script to find the correct entry on your website, and if it isn't available, use the internet archive. It will take a while before all links are fixed; the script tries to fix all MSDN blog links, not just yours, and since it bumps posts to the homepage, unlike [one of the staff's tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314169/295232) (which can't fix these cases) I've imposed a rate limit on it.

Answer (score 10):

It isn't required or allowed because it's redundant. If all `const` members are static, then only confusion can arise from allowing *some* of them to be specified as `static` and some of them not to be.

Comment: But that was my question, why not force them all to be static?

Comment: @Adam: But you could *require* the static keyword, instead of requiring its absence.

Comment: Because there's no way for them *not* to be static. Why require a redundant term?

Comment: Thats a good point, but leaving off highly descriptive terms is something I would consider confusing (...as I did :) ).

Comment: @Nick: If you're saying that anything "highly descriptive" should be required, why not require `readonly` on the variable as well?

Comment: readonly and const are different, but it isnt letting me post my other comment... no i wouldn't specify that you must pass things by value, but it passing by value or reference doesn't appear to outright break any other language rules.

Comment: @Nick: It doesn't break any language rules; you stated that your objection was that it's leaving out "descriptive" information, but passing by value is descriptive, as is marking the constant as read only; they're also just as redundant as marking a constant `static`. If you know what `const` means in C#, then how does it possibly even appear to be breaking any language rules?

Comment: By specifying a const without a static modifier, it appears to break other language rules when used in a static method because you cannot normally call non static fields from static methods. It appears to be doing this when static isnt explicitly specified.  I say that makes it highly descriptive. And you are right, if I knew what const meant, it wouldn't appear to break any rules.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason to disallow declare constants as static is that from CLR point of view the constants are not not stored in memory along with other static fields of the type.

The constants don't have memory address and you cannot get reference to the constant value (the only exception is string constants). At runtime the type holding constant definition won't be loaded if other static/nonstatic members are not referenced. If it is the only type in the assembly, you can even safely delete it's DLL from the disk after compilation.

So, the constants are 'static' only in terms of 'may be referenced from static methods'. Constants do not have any other 'static' properties as other static type members do.