# why cannot declare const static string inside a class

Tags: c#

why cannot declare const static string inside a class? Have to use static readonly

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631975/c-using-consts-in-static-classes/2632844#2632844 Also see my article on the subject for details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/10/don-t-repeat-yourself-consts-are-already-static.aspx

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the C# language (as well as PHP), `const` is implicitly `static`, so you don't use both keywords together. This is unlike C and C++ where `const` doesn't say if a variable is static or not, just that its value is not modifiable.

You declare a constant string like this:

```
const string SomeConstant = "abc";
```

There's a slight difference between `const` fields and static `readonly` fields too, but both are similar in that you can't change their values. Details are in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55984/what-is-the-difference-between-const-and-readonly).

Answer (score 1):

> All constants declarations are
>   implicitly static, and the C#
>   specification states that the
>   (redundant) inclusion of the static
>   modifier is prohibited. I believe this
>   is to avoid the confusion which could
>   occur if a reader were to see two
>   constants, one declared static and one
>   not - they could easily assume that
>   the difference in specification
>   implied a difference in semantics.
>   Having said that, there is no
>   prohibition on redundantly specifying
>   an access modifier which is also the
>   default one, where there is a choice.
>   For instance, a (concrete) method can
>   be explicitly marked as private
>   despite that being the default. The
>   rule appears to be that where there is
>   no choice (e.g. a method declaration
>   in an interface) the redundant
>   modifier is prohibited. Where there is
>   a choice, it's allowed.

Taken from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/why-can-t-i-use-code-static-code-and-code-const-code-together.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have written a blog on this, which will give you a better understanding.Have a look http://anishmarokey.blogspot.com/2009/09/const-vs-fields.html

mostly `primitive` types used as Constant other as `static readonly`