# Why Are Parentheses Required on C# Static Constructors?

Tags: c#, syntactic-sugar, static-constructor

Consider:

```
class Foo
{
    static Foo()
    {
        // Static initialisation
    }
}
```

Why are the `()` required in `static Foo() {...}`? The static constructor must always be parameterless, so why bother? Are they necessary to avoid some parser ambiguity, or is it just to maintain consistency with regular parameterless constructors?

Since it looks so much like an initialiser block, I often find myself leaving them out by accident and then have to think for a few seconds about what is wrong. It would be nice if they could be elided in the same way.

Comment: If these sorts of aspects of language design interest you, you might want to read my articles on a similar design issue: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/20/ambiguous-optional-parentheses.aspx

Comment: @Eric Lippert: I am already an avid reader of your blog (and I think that's where I learned the word 'elided'). :) Rereading those articles however, it seems like none of the ambiguities created by making empty parens optional in method/constructor calls apply to the static constructor case (mostly because you can't explicitly call the thing). Is there also an ambiguity in this case, or is it just a matter of not being worth it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I get this sort of question frequently; that is, the question "the compiler could work out that this thing is missing, so why is it required?" Here's another example of this sort of question:

[C# using consts in static classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631975/c-using-consts-in-static-classes/2632844#2632844)

As I noted in that question, basically we have three choices in that situation. Make the redundant text required, make it optional, or make it illegal.

Each has its own downside.

The downside of making it required is you end up with an unnecessary redundancy in the language.

The downside of making it optional is you confuse people who think there must be a difference between the two forms. Also, you make it harder for the error-recovering parser to do its work; it thrives on redundancy. And you potentially make it harder to add new language features in the future, because more "syntactic area" is already claimed.

The downside of making it illegal is you then make a "gotcha", where the user has to remember that oh, yeah, I'm supposed to put parens here, but not here.

The proposed feature had better have an upside that pays for the downside. The smallest downside seems to me to be the first: make it required. The other options I would want to have an upside that justifies the downside, and I'm not seeing one here.

Comment: It's interesting that in the `static const` case you came down on the side of "It's just more typing without adding clarity or expressiveness to the language" but in this case it's "you potentially make it harder to add new language features in the future". I guess it's a case of how much redundancy vs. how much lost potential?

Comment: @veredesmarald: Yes, it's a judgment call every time. In this particular case I think making it optional just in this case would be a weird inconsistency; why not allow *any* method that takes no parameters to have its parameter list elided? What is so special about static constructors?

Comment: Also interesting is that you mention making it illegal creates a "gotcha", while I find the "gotcha" is having to include them. I think this is a combination of my frequent use of initialisers with parameterless constructors, and also a holdover from my java days, where `static` blocks don't have parens.

Comment: As you mentioned in your series, you can't make them optional on just any call as it leads to ambiguities; static cons are special as the ambiguities mentioned don't apply to them (as far as I can tell) because of the limited number of places they can occur. I guess I can buy the inconsistency angle, though in my mind statics cons are already a separate beast to regular cons/method calls, perhaps this is just an oddness in how I view aspects of the language.

Answer (score 11):

Because it's a static **constructor**, so it's `static` + a normal-looking constructor.

Consistency is key. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would assume it's for disambiguity:  it makes the parser's job easier, recognising the code block as a *constructor subroutine* (irrespective of `static`ness);  and conversely it helps ensure that the human author/maintainer is aware of the implications of choosing this particular construct, by forcing them to use a specific *method*-like syntax.